# Javascript Mirror html object

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I have html with variables

```
html = `<div>${product.id}<img src="${product.src}"/></div>`
```

then I update the dom simply with

```
document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = html;
```

so far so good, problem is the html contains images and everytime I update, the page flickers, I was thinking if there was a more unintrusive method to only update the changed values

Comment: *only update the changed values* If you're doing this a lot, for more complicated setups, this is exactly (one of) the problems frameworks like React were designed to help with

Comment: If the `<img>`s are different, not sure there's any way to avoid a moderate amount of re-rendering, assuming you don't want to be stuck showing the old image

Comment: what kind of framework are you using? And where is your data update codes?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I know, but the scope of this project is to small and built on a prexisting system, to bother to implement React, worst case scenario I'll have to fragment the html

Comment: If the `<img>`s are different, some sort of flickering will be *expected* when one image changes to the other - there's not really any way to avoid that

Comment: @Raptor no other framework

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes of course, but more often than rarely its the same image

Comment: Other way is to add all images and display them in sequence to avoid flickering

Answer (score 0):

Hide the images when appending to DOM, then toggle visibility when the image finishes loading. https://jsfiddle.net/ftpd9sxz/

```
function showImage() {
    this.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
let product = {
    id: 2,
    src: "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1010263656456744960/bXOUw0hb_bigger.jpg"
}
let html = `<div>${product.id}<img src="${product.src}" style="visibility: hidden" /></div>`;

document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = html;
document.querySelector('.container img').addEventListener("load", showImage);
```